# Solve the following system of system of equations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Solve the following system of system of equations :
$$
A \cap X = B \\
A \cup X = C 
$$
and
in which $B \subseteq A \subseteq C$
is assumed. Can someone tell me what I have to do here?

Comment: this is exersise from my homework

Comment: You have stated what you are given but you haven't stated what the problem is

Comment: i have to solve this,i am not sure how that's way i ask here

Comment: One usually (#) solves for $X$. (#) That custom seems to originate from the time when arabic sources were translated in Spain. The arabic original term meaning 'something' or such, according to some TED talk.

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: https://www.ted.com/talks/terry_moore_why_is_x_the_unknown

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

What elements must be deleted from $A$ to get $B$?  Those should not be in $X$.  What additional elements must be inserted to get $C$?  Those should be in $X$.

Comment: i understand what you mean but i can't sove it,i think about that for hours

Answer (score 0):

Hint: A Venn diagram might help to express $X$ in terms of $A$, $B$ and $C$.

[image: venn diagram]

Spoiler:

> $$ X = C \setminus (A \setminus B) $$

Answer (score 0):

So I'm assuming you are supposed to describe $X$ in terms of $A, B,$ and $C$.

Preliminaries:  $B \subseteqq A \subseteq C$.

We can break $C$ into three disjoint sets:

$S1$ = all elements of B = $B$.

$S2$ = all elements of A that are not in B = $B' \cap A$. ($Z'$ means the compliment of $Z$).

$S3$ = all elements of C that are not in A = $A' \cap C$.

So $C = B \cup S2 \cup S3$ and $B, S2, S3$ are disjoint.

So $X \cap C = (X \cap B) \cup (X \cap S2) \cup (X \cap S3)$.

Now we can solve:

1) $X \cap B$

$X \cap A = B \implies B \subseteq X \implies$

$X \cap B = B$

2) $X \cap S2$

$X \cap A = B$ hence no element of A that is not in B is in X.  i.e. $(B' \cap A) \cap X = \emptyset$.

So $X \cap S2 = \emptyset$

3) $X \cap S3$

$X \cup A = C$.  So X contains all points of C that are not in A.  i.e. $S3 = A' \cap C \subseteq X$ so

$X \cap S3 = S3$

So

$X \cap C = B \cup \emptyset \cup S3 = B \cup (A' \cap C)$.

But we have been told $A \cup X = C$ so $X \subseteq C$.

So $X \cap C = X = B \cup (A' \cap C)$.

Comment: so you think that this resolve is not right

Comment: so you think that this resolve is not right

Comment: @mvw All I can say is ".... Oh, duh!"  You are absolutely right of course.   *BIG* oversight on my part.

Comment: @p.mc I'm pretty sure my resolve is still correct.  The only differenct is where I said "we might as well assume C is the universal set" and "X \cap C" is the best we can do.  X subset C so X \cap C = X.

Comment: @mvw "so X contains all elements of C (..) that are not in A"  Okay, *this* time *I* am right because you misunderstand what I said.  I said X contains all those points, which is does.  I did not say that X *only* contained those points and no others.  I thought it was clear (Note I *did* say $A' \cap C$ was a *subset* of X$; not *equal* to X \cap C.) but I guess it wasn't.  I'll try to work on a clearer statement.